# Implement the .split method

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I need to implement the .split method in my own way without using prebuilt functions. The method should receive a string divided into 2 sentences by a dot and divide them through a separator.
For example, there is this string:
'word wooord wooooooooord wooooooord. wooooooooord woooooord woooord wooooooooord', separator in this case: '. '
The result should be:
['word wooord wooooooooord wooooooord", "wooooooooord woooooord woooord wooooooooord']

I tried to implement it myself, the first problem I encountered is that the words from the string are added character by character to the new array. The second problem is that the output is still a string even though I declared an array earlier.

```
function split(str, splitter){
    let arrSent = []
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        if (str[i] != splitter){
            arrSent += str[i]
        }
    }
    return arrSent
}
console.log(split('word wooord wooooooooord wooooooord. wooooooooord woooooord woooord wooooooooord', '. '))
```

Comment: `[] + ''` returns a string. You probably mean `arrSent[arrSent.length - 1] += str[i]`. You have to add empty strings to the array.

Comment: Also, what you're forgetting is that `str[i] != splitter` will **never pass** since your delimiter (*"splitter"*) uses **two** characters as input, while `str[i]` represents only **one** character at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the delimiter can have more than one character, you need a system to upfront collect a ***sample*** of characters (of the same length as the delimiter) to be then compared with the delimiter:

```js
const split = (str, delimiter) => {

  // If delimiter is empty string just return an array of characters
  if (delimiter === "") return [...str];

  const len = delimiter.length;
  const iter = str.length - len + 1; // max needed iterations
  const arr = [""]; // Prefill it with empty string
  let idx = 0; // arr insertion pointer
  
  for (let i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
  
    // Collect len chars from str as a sample
    // to compare with the delimiter:
    let sample = "";
    for (let x = i; x < i + len; x++) {
      sample += str[x];
    }
    
    const isSplit = sample === delimiter;
    const isEnded = i === iter - 1;

    if (isSplit) {
      i += len - 1;  // Consume splitted characters
      idx += 1;      // Increment arr pointer
      arr[idx] = ""; // Prepare the new array key as empty string
    } else {
      // If loop ended append the entire sample.
      // Otherwise, append a single character:
      arr[idx] += isEnded ? sample : str[i];
    }
  }
  
  return arr
}

console.log(split("word. etc", ". "));
console.log(split("word. etc. ", ". "));
console.log(split(". word yep. . etc. ", ". "));
console.log(split("word", ". "));
console.log(split("word", "word"));
console.log(split("word", ""));
console.log(split("", ""));
```

above, `idx` (starting at `0`) is used as the output's `arr` insertion pointer. The `idx` is incremented if the `sample` matches the `delimiter`. Also, if there's a match, we need to skip iterations `i += len`, to not include the delimiter in the output array.

To test, create many examples and right before `return arr;` use `console.log(JSON.stringify(arr) === JSON.stringify(str.split(delimiter)));` - it should return `true` for all the submitted tests.

Comment: Instead of using `arr[idx] ??= "";`, just put `arr[idx] = "";` inside the `if` statement that increments `idx`

Comment: @Bergi nice suggestion. Actually even more intuitive and faster.

Comment: Btw this has a bug when the input ends with a delimiter, you'll want to put the `arr[idx] += str[i];` in an `else` block. *Edit:* …and start with `const arr = [""];`

Comment: @Bergi that fixed it! Well spotted.

Comment: I'd do `if (sample === delimiter) { arr[idx+=len] = ""; i += len; } else { arr[idx] += str[i]; i += 1; }` then use no increment in the loop. This gets us the expected empty string in the result when the input ends with the delimiter.

Comment: Ah right. It doesn't handle the input `"word yep. . etc. "` correctly though, where two delimiters are consecutive.

Comment: @Bergi improved. Now it should work as expected for any edge cases. Tested using `console.log(JSON.stringify(arr) === JSON.stringify(str.split(delimiter)));` It has also the *isEnded* improvement to limit unneeded loops.

Comment: Improved the demo to handle split by empty string as well.